# Why isn't my value stored in the database with LINQ?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm using the following LINQ-statement to update a table-entry with the current date/time:

```
MembershipClassesDataContext db = new MembershipClassesDataContext();
var tmp = db.drun_addqol_2_usrs.SingleOrDefault(y => !y.done.HasValue && y.UserId.Equals(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()));
tmp.done = DateTime.Now;
// at this point, tmp.done has the correct value!
// also the entry isn't null because I got the correct ID with tmp.UserId
// But db.GetChangeSet().Count is zero (0), so the value of "done" is changed but not commited to the ChangeSet?!
db.SubmitChanges();
```

"done" is a column with type DateTime and after the above query it shouldn't be null but should contain the actual date / time. But... it doesn't update and the value is still null.

Any ideas where my mistake is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting any exception, if SingleOrDefault can return null if any no record matching criteria. Otherwise code looks ok.

Comment: I wrote some comments to the above code - I got no exceptions and tmp is the correct entry. Also tmp.done isn't null anymore but the current date, but it's not saved to the DB because the ChangeSet is still empty...

Comment: FYI: For the moment I added a trigger to my SQL database to change the field "done" to the actual date - but it's only a work-around and not a final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is the object being returned from SingleOrDefault one that already exists in the DB, or a new default object?  if it's a new then you have to add it to the dataset or .submitchanges will not save it.

Comment: for the sake of argument try adding before your save.  Nothing in your comments indicates that this object without a doubt already exists in the db.  If this line works (or doesn't work) we can rule out this possibility.

Add is slightly different for Linq2entities vs. linqtosql, if you tell me which you are using i can give an example.

Comment: I'm using Linq2Sql - and won't the entry be duplicated if it already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Before you call db.SubmitChanges(), call db.GetChangeSet() to determine if L2S thinks it has any rows to update. If the changeset is empty then your SingleOrDefault() method must be returning nothing.

Comment: I made some small changes to the code sample. "Tmp" is the correct entry. Also "tmp.done" isn't null after setting it to DateTime.now, but the changed entry is not saved to the DB because the ChangeSet is still empty.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that "tmp" is not an entity that your DB context is aware of. It's an anonymous variable. You need to actually modify an entity tracked by the context.

Comment: I used the anonymous tmp variable only to check the selected entry. The changed entry isn't saved even when I wrote:

db.drun_addqol_2_usrs.SingleOrDefault(...).done = DateTime.Now;

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question - In the designer code for your drun_addqol_2_usrs, does the if statement for the setter evaluate to true (and call the property changed stuff)?

```
set
{
    if ((this._done != value))
    {
        this.OndoneChanging(value);
        this.SendPropertyChanging();
        this._done = value;
        this.SendPropertyChanged("done");
        this.OndoneChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sry for my late reply - I checked the setter and it's actually there and is calling all those stuff.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if tmp is attached to your datacontext?

Try -

```
db.drun_addqol_2_usrs.Attach(tmp)
```

and then call

```
SubmitChanges()
```

it'll either work, or it'll throw an exception complaining that it can't attach an entity to a data context when it's already attached to a data context, or something like that.